# Firebase Cloud Messaging (Flutter): Error message when subscribing to topic

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have included Firebase Messaging in my app and I am getting the following error when I try to subscribe to topics.

```
FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method Messaging#subscribeToTopic, errorOrNil => {
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Invalid registration response :'Error=INVALID_PARAMETERS'. It is missing 'token' field.";
}
flutter: subscription error: [firebase_messaging/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.
```

As you can see it simply says "An unknown error has occurred", which is not very helpful to me.

Here is my code which is meant to obtain permissions for push notifications, then gets the token and subscribes to a list of topics...

```
  Future<void> requestMessagingPermission() async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted notifiactions permission');
      messaging.getToken().then((token) async {
        print('Messaging token: $token');

        //configure notification topics
        //gets a list of strings (topic names) from provider and loops through them to subscribe to them all

        GlobalProvider provider = context.read<GlobalProvider>();
        if (provider.notificationTopicsSet == false) {
          //subscribe to topics
          for (var topic in provider.notificationTopics) {
            print('topic subscribing... $topic');
            try {
              await messaging.subscribeToTopic(topic).then((value) => print('topic subscribed: $topic'));
            } catch (e) {
              print('subscription error: $e');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I am getting the same error in the console for every topic that is being looped through and subscribed to. The weird thing is that push notifications were working before, but now they don't seem to be.

I have tried updating Flutter to the latest version (3.3.7), I have tried updating both the Firebase Core package (2.1.1) and the Firebase messaging package to their latest versions (14.0.4) and I am still getting the error.

*From pubspec.yaml:*

```
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.0.4
```

What is this `token` that is missing? The `subscribeToTopic()` function only seems to take the topic name string. Am I missing something?

Thank you, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this logs something? print('Messaging token: $token');

It should log a valid token and firebase will use that implicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ended up being only an issue with the iOS simulator. The error did not occur with the Android emulator and push notifications work fine on physical devices.

Comment: Has anyone got a solution to this? I still experience this on emulator